# How to avoid page locks causing deadlocks with concurrent updates to different rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-deadlocks

```
CREATE TABLE MY_DATA (
    FIRST_KEY VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    SECOND_KEY VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    AUTO_VALUE INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    DATA_FIELD_1 VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    DATA_FIELD_2 VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    DATA_FIELD_3 VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    DATA_FIELD_4 VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    DATA_FIELD_5 VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    DATA_FIELD_6 VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    DATA_FIELD_7 VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    DATA_FIELD_8 VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    DATA_FIELD_9 VARCHAR(255) NULL
);

ALTER TABLE MY_DATA ADD CONSTRAINT PK_MY_DATA FIRST_KEY PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (FIRST_KEY);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_MY_DATA_SECOND_KEY ON TABLE MY_DATA (SECOND_KEY);
```

-- The SECOND_KEY is a Foreign Key that is changed based on data fields, as follows (the data field part of the WHERE clause changes each time, as to which fields and values).  This is when the deadlock occurs.

-- The AUTO_VALUE is being used to break the updates into chunks (and each set of updates is being done in parallel).

**First Process**

```
UPDATE SET SECOND_KEY=NULL WHERE SECOND_KEY="old value" AND AUTO_VALUE IS BETWEEN 1 AND 250000;
UPDATE SET SECOND_KEY="new value" WHERE SECOND_KEY IS NULL AND AUTO_VALUE IS BETWEEN 1 AND 250000 AND DATA_FIELD_3='d3 value' AND DATA_FIELD_5 != 'unwanted value';
```

**Second Process**

```
UPDATE SET SECOND_KEY=NULL WHERE SECOND_KEY="old value" AND AUTO_VALUE IS BETWEEN 250001 AND 500000;
UPDATE SET SECOND_KEY="new value" WHERE SECOND_KEY IS NULL AND AUTO_VALUE IS BETWEEN 250001 AND 500000 AND DATA_FIELD_3='d3 value' AND DATA_FIELD_5 != 'unwanted value';
```

**Deadlock Situation**

I am seeing a deadlock with the first process having a "U" page lock and the second process wants a "IX" page lock on the same page.  For a different page, the second process has a "IX" page lock, and the first process wants a "U" page lock for that page.

**Other Table Uses**

These queries are not done when changing the SECOND_KEY.

-- Table DATA_FIELD changes are done by looking up the primary key

-- The data is read by other queries looking up by the second key

Comment: Is it intentional that in your second process, `AUTO_VALUE` has `BETWEEN 250001 AND 500000` in the first statement but `BETWEEN 1 AND 250000` in the second statement? I assume that's why you're getting logs on the same pages.

Comment: If the range is not overlapped, you can try to force SQL to use row lock : UPDATE MY_DATA WITH(ROWLOCK) SET ...

Comment: I have edited Second Process, the ranges do not overlap.

Comment: My worry with ROWLOCK is that the table is quite large; how much will this affect performance?

Comment: You said the deadlock involves the queries trying to update the same pages.  The question is: pages *on which index*?  The clustered index, or the nonclustered index, or both?